# What is the base class of a Mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

If I have a mocked object:

```
var mock = new Mock<myClass>();
```

What would be the base class of `mock`?

---

The reason for my question is because I've got the following that I am debugging:

```
var mock = new Mock<myClass>();
mock.Object.someMethod(); //stepping through this line by line, it does not set focus to **myClass**
```

However, when I set the CallBase to true, I DO see that the compiler is running through code in **myClass**:

```
var mock = new Mock<myClass>();
mock.CallBase = true;
mock.Object.someMethod();
```

**Does this mean that the base class of a mock is the class that it is mocking?**

Comment: The Interface you are trying to use in your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it does is actually create and instance of your class with the default constructor of your class and then overrides the public virtual methods of your class in reflection.

The default behavior of the methods is to do nothing.
When you say `mock.Callbase = true` it tells the mock that if you didnt supply any setup function it should use the method of the type its mocking.

You can look at it as if the mock is deriving from your class and overrides the methods and if you set `mock.Callbase = true` it calls the `base.someMethod()`. But really its not, meaning the cast to your class will fail, because it is doing it in reflection

Hope I explained myself

Answer (score 1):

No, this dont mean this, with `mock.CallBase = true;` you tell to **Moq** use the instance of the type directly. **[Moq.CallBase](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/IMock(T)/P/CallBase)**.

It implements something like a **[Proxy-Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern)** about the type in the generic param, but you just can **stub** `virtual` methods **(Whatever exists workarounds to stub some non virtual method)**, for example if you pass an `interface` in the generic param you can **stub** all method and properties, but if you pass a concrete class only `virtual` methods you can **stub** the return.

Comment: thank you. i dont understand what this means Whether the base member virtual implementation will be called for mocked classes if no setup is matched

Comment: when would you ever want the Callbase to be false??

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Often, but exist exceptions, i say often because in an unit test you are testing the unit and  all the mock objects are dependencies, so you will testing if the mocks are been called not what they do.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' If CallBase is true then any calls against the Mock that don't have a setup will call the base class.

Comment: @lukew thank you, that just shook my entire understanding of what mock tests are .

Comment: so im not understanding, if you are  setting everything up, then of course everything will succeed, what is the point of setting everything up vs. using callback = true

Comment: when you setup a method to be called, let's say sut.Setup(x=>x.Consume(mockMessage.Object));   --- does this mean that it will call the method consume or not?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I advise you to dont use mock in the SUT, use mock only in the dependencies of the SUT.

Comment: why do you say that? in this case it will not be a unit test?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Because the SUT must to be tested as concrete not a mock.

Comment: what if i want to verify that LogCatcher was called? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByqKtGmtuLzZM1p4MVE0MFhWbWc/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: `LogCatcher` call method of some dependency?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105590/discussion-between-l-and-joel-ramos-michaliszen).

Comment: logcatcher of the SUT

Answer (score 0):

It does not necessarily have a base class at all.

When you type the code you have, you're creating an instance of the class Mock for the concrete type of **myClass**

```
class myClass<T>
{
  private T _Instance;

  public myClass(T instance){
  _Instance = instance;
}
```

As in the example above, no baseClass for "myClass"

Comment: when would you ever want the Callbase to be false??